# ng-init is not working with ng-if

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive, angular-filters

I have a div

`<div class="error-text" ng-if="customerIdLength > customerIdMaxLength" ng-init="error='yes'" >Error presented</div>`

here `ng-if` is working properly.

**But**

Based on `ng-init` value i am disabling a button like this:

```
<button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" ng-click="submitNumber();" ng-disabled="error=='yes'">Submit</button>
```

this is not working. **If** i am putting this `ng-init` to some other element which don't have `ng-if` then it is working properly. So what is the reason behind?

Comment: use `ng-hide/ng-show` these create DOM element but hide / show depending on condition which will invoke` ng-init` but ng-if will stop creating DOM element which will stop ng-init invokation

Comment: I already tried `ng-show/ng-hide` but the problem is my button will be disabled in both hide and show condition.

Comment: @Arpit Meena, so, you want to disable button when error text is shown, but when error text is hidden, button must be enabled?

Comment: Yes exactly i want the same.

Comment: your second code is not working?

Comment: @ArpitMeena If any of these answers solved your problem, you can always mark them as accepted

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="myApp">

<head>
 
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
 
</head>

<body data-ng-controller="testController">

  <div class="error-text" ng-init="$parent.error='yes'" ng-if="1 > 0">Error presented</div>

  <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" ng-click="submitNumber();" ng-disabled="error=='yes'">Submit</button>

  <script>
    // Code goes here

    angular
      .module('myApp', [])

    .controller('testController', ['$scope',
      function($scope) {

      }
    ])
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

you need to use $parent to get inner scope inside ng-if.

Comment: Disable is working now how can i enable the button on hide of error?

Comment: just change the ng-if condition to false,and see

Answer (score 0):

The difference between [ng-if](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) and [ng-show](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) is that `ng-if` actually REMOVES the html element attached to it from the DOM, causing your `ng-init` expression not to be executed.

Simply replacing it by `ng-show` should do the trick

```
<div class="error-text" ng-show="customerIdLength" ng-init="error='yes'">Error presented</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the logic is sound but it might be missing some angularjs setup and configuration like ng-app and ng-controller declaration in the markup.

Ensure that this is declared at the top

```
<div ng-app="github" ng-controller="githubRepos">
<!-- Your code -->
</div>
```

[**Solution**](http://codepen.io/JLC007/pen/bBGrej)